# Using variables amidst html in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, html, server

Here's the deal:

- I already have node.js server which communicates with a database;
- I need to create a webpage for people to access and check leader-boards
  from the database (the server queries the database to show the users
  with top 10 scores);

The example below shows a server responding with html;

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write('<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n' +
'<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Test web page on node.js</title>\n' +
'<style type="text/css">* {font-family:arial, sans-serif;}</style>\n' +
'</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Euro 2012 teams</h1>\n' +
'<div id="content"><p>The teams in Group D for Euro 2012 are:</p><ul><li>England</li><li>France</li><li>Sweden</li><li>Ukraine</li></ul></div>' +
'\n</body>\n</html>');
res.end();
}).listen(8888, 'address');
console.log('Server running at http://address:8888');
```

- How would I go about to do something similar but instead the list would be the result of a query to the database?

Note:
I already know how to query, I only need to know how to have the results shows in the HTML code above

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most modern web applications solve this problem by using a [template engine.](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#templating) You asked for something similar, and this is likely the better way to go about it.

A template allows you to have a file or simply a string with variable placeholders and then you can pass a model (in this case, your return value from the database) to the template, render it, and send that to the client.

Depending on the database you're using, you will have to likely start making your queries using Node.js's asynchronous patterns. Generally when you make a query in Node.js you will follow a pattern similar to

```
...
db.create({"name" : "rawr"}, 
 function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
     // handle error
   }
   // build your template
   // res.send the compiled HTML
 });
...
```

Of course this all depends on the database that you're using, but generally it will look something like that. If you're comfortable with HTML I recommend looking into [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) but also loking at the link provided above for a few more and find one you like. Without a few more details such as constraints or database being used, this is about as much as I can say.